# How is the distance of an 3d object measured in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I obtained 3d image using 2d urg-04lx-ug01 .There is an object at a distance of 1 meter. How do ı see that distance in Rviz or in a terminal ? or can ı see object distance ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271716/how-is-the-distance-of-an-3d-object-measured-in-ros/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz has a measure tool that displays distances between objects.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-09-28**:
I know it too. But ı want to see the distance of any object automatically Mr. @dornhege